# To prove these sets are equal without using modulo arithmetic.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Prove $\{3t : t \in \mathbb Z\} \cup \{3t + 1 : t \in \mathbb Z\} \cup \{3t + 2 : t\in \mathbb Z\} = \mathbb Z.$

Comment: $\subseteq$ is trivial. For $\supseteq$, you need to know about division with remainder, though whether you consider that a part of "modulo arithmetic" is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 2):

Discuss the  remainder of the Euclidean division  by $3$.